# Stub Update an Entity in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I want update an entity property(`Count`) in Entity Framework 6 with stub update manner, indeed i want plus one `Count` property value Without query database. How i can do this?

```
      //...
      var stub = new entity {Id = id};
      _articles.Attach(stub);

      stub.Count++; // Count always is 1! How i can do this without fetch/query database?
      context.SaveChanges();
      //...
```

Comment: Well, you need *some* sort of current value to be able to increment it. I don't know how you could get that other than from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of is to use a stored procedure.

```
create proc sp_UpdateCount @Id int
as
update [dbo].[EntityTable] set [Count] = [Count] + 1
where [Id] = @Id
```

and then run it in the code

```
SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter("@Id", id);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_UpdateCount @Id", paramId);
```

Please note this will run the procedure immediately and you don't have to call SaveChanges for it. If you want to execute the procedure in a transaction with other changes make sure you create one explicitly with TransactionScope.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user197508 hi there, you didn't make any comments to my answer, just wonder if it was helpful to you? If not is there is anything I can do to help you with your question?